# Generating random math equation using tree - Avoiding Parentheses

Tags: math, tree, swift, equation, parentheses

**Edit:** This was originally on programmers.stackexchange.com, but since I already had some code I thought it might be better here.

I am trying to generate a random math problem/equation. After researching the best (and only) thing I found was this question: [Generating random math expression](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/195813/generating-random-math-expression). Because I needed all 4 operations, and the app that I will be using this in is targeted at kids, I wanted to be able to insure that all numbers would be positive, division would come out even, etc, I decided to use a tree.

I have the tree working, and it can generate an equation as well as evaluate it to a number. The problem is that I am having trouble getting it to only use parentheses when needed. I have tried several solutions, that primaraly involve:

- Seeing if this node is on the right of the parent node
- Seeing if the node is more/less important then it's parent node (* > +, etc).
- Seeing if the node & it's parent are of the same type, and if so if the order matters for that operation.

Not that it matters, I am using Swift, and here is what I have so far:

```
func generateString(parent_node:TreeNode) -> String {
    if(self.is_num){
        return self.equation!
    }

    var equation = self.equation!
    var left_equation  : String = self.left_node!.generateString(self)
    var right_equation : String = self.right_node!.generateString(self)

    // Conditions for ()s

    var needs_parentheses = false

    needs_parentheses = parent_node.importance > self.importance
    needs_parentheses = (
                            needs_parentheses
                            ||
                            (
                                parent_node.right_node?.isEqualToNode(self)
                                &&
                                parent_node.importance <= self.importance
                                &&
                                (
                                    parent_node.type != self.type
                                    &&
                                    ( parent_node.order_matters != true || self.order_matters != true )
                                )
                            )
                        )
    needs_parentheses = (
                            needs_parentheses
                            &&
                            (
                                !(
                                    self.importance > parent_node.importance
                                 )
                            )
                        )

    if (needs_parentheses) {
        equation = "(\(equation))"
    }
    return equation.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("a", withString: left_equation).stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("b", withString: right_equation)
}
```

I have not been able to get this to work, and have been banging my head against the wall about it.

The only thing I could find on the subject of removing parentheses is this: [How to get rid of unnecessary parentheses in mathematical expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063316/how-to-get-rid-of-unnecessary-parentheses-in-mathematical-expression), and I could not figure out how to apply it to my use case. Also, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063316/how-to-get-rid-of-unnecessary-parentheses-in-mathematical-expression), and I might try to build a parser (using [PEGKit](https://github.com/itod/pegkit)), but I wanted to know if anybody had a good idea to either determine where parentheses need to go, or put them everywhere and remove the useless ones.

**EDIT:** Just to be clear, I don't need someone to write this for me, I am just looking for what it needs to do.

**EDIT 2:** Since this app will be targeted at kids, I would like to use the least amount of parentheses possible, while still having the equation come out right. Also, the above algorithm does not put *enough* parentheses.

Comment: Do you find that indentation with all those 'hanging parens' readable?

Comment: @GoZoner, I am not sure what you mean. I was able to read the equation with the extra parentheses, but it was less readable then I would have liked. Plus, if the app is targeted at kids, Simpler is better. Also, please see the updated question.

Answer (score -1):

I have coded a python 3 pgrm that does NOT use a tree, but does successfully generate valid equations with integer solutions and it uses all four operations plus parenthetical expressions.  My target audience is 5th graders practicing order of operations (PEMDAS).

```
872  = 26 * 20 + (3 + 8) * 16 * 2      
251  = 256 - 3 - 6 + 8 / 2         
367  = 38 * 2 + (20 + 15) + 16 ** 2         
260  = 28 * 10 - 18 - 4 / 2         
5000 = 40 * 20 / 4 * 5 ** 2         
211  = 192 - 10 / 2 / 1 + 24         
1519 = 92 * 16 + 6 + 25 + 16
```

If the python of any interest to you ... I am working on translating the python into JavaScript and make a web page available for students and teachers.

Comment: Answer doesn't seem related to the question. Also, asking people to do things for you in an answer isn't helpful to others.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Maclean, I edited my org post, hopefully adding some clarity. If you still find my post irrelevant and in any way offensive, I will gladly delete my org comment.